# Ubuntu Studio 23.10 - command line when I choose Try

Tags: boot, command-line, usb

I'm a long time Linux "tryout", but always used Windows due to my work and softwares that never existed in Linux environment.
But recently I decided to try Linux Ubuntu Studio (I work with photography and video editing, and for that I know there are software available)

I downloaded Ubuntu Studio 23.10 and made an USB boot drive. I restarted the computer, went to the BIOS and made it boot from USB. I was presented with the Linux options menu and as I was not entirely ready to install it, I wanted to try first so I picked Try Ubuntu. A few seconds after, I'm taken to a blank command line with a blinking cursor and thats it. I typed "help", but I actually didn't understood what was written back, some sort of errors. Then I typed "exit", same thing. Ok, I unplugged the USB and hit the reset button.

I do not know any Linux commands, so I was cough off guard with that command line. I thought it should take me to a desktop environment or something to try Linux Ubuntu Studio.

Maybe I should try the version 22 instead?

Comment: The actual error message after you typed "help" would be useful to include in the question. A blinking cursor usually points to a graphics problem, but such a screen doesn't respond to typing.

Comment: Well, it actually was a command-line interface, it was not a blank screen. Thats why I decided to type "help". But I can try this again later and provide some more exact feedback.